Ocelot Routing issue when use {Literals} at last
I have multiple route configurations in ocelot.json
{
    "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/{Version}/List/{ListId}",
    "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/Api/{Version}/List/{ListId}",
    ...
    ...
},
{
    "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/{Version}/List/{ListId}/View/{ViewId}/Records",
    "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/Api/{Version}/List/{ListId}/View/{ViewId}/Records",
    ...
    ...
}

GET http1.1

http://localhost/V1/List/100/View/256/Records

Above GET request matches first route instead of second one.
I can resolve this issue by specifying high priority to second one. Here, I expect best match instead of first match. Is there any solution to do so?
Specifications

Version: 23.2.2
Platform: Winodws 0x64
Subsystem: N.A

